# Using bullet in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I have a plot and I would like to use something like the picture given below as xticks. But there seems to be no way to put this bullet like symbol in matplotlib. How can I do that?

Text for matplotlib xtick

[image: Text for matplotlib xtick]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render your ticklabels using LaTeX. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# example data
x = np.linspace(0, 2, 250)
y = np.exp(x)

# plot data using latex rendered label
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xticks(ticks = [1], labels = [r'$Text\,- \bullet -$'])
```

The LaTeX symbol you are looking for is `\bullet`.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for!